# Force updates on installed PWA when changing index.html (prevent caching)

Tags: reactjs, caching, updates, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I am building a react app, which consists in a Single Page Application, hosted on Amazon S3.

Sometimes, I deploy a change to the back-end and to the front-end at the same time, and I need all the browser sessions to start running the new version, or at least those whose sessions start after the last front-end deploy.

What happens is that many of my users still running the old front-end version on their phones ***for weeks***, which is not compatible with the new version of the back-end anymore, but some of them get the updates by the time they start the next session.

As I use Webpack to build the app, it generates bundles with hashes in their names, while the `index.html` file, which defines the bundles that should be used, is uploaded with the following cache-control property: `"no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"`. The service worker file has the same cache policy.

The idea is that the user's browser can cache everything, execpt for the first files they need. The plan was good, but I'm replacing the `index.html` file with a newer version and my users are not refetching this file when they restart the app.

Is there a definitive guide or a way to workaround that problem?

I also know that a PWA should work offline, so it has to have the ability to cache to reuse, but this idea doesn't help me to perform a massive and instantaneous update as well, right?

What are the best options I have to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got the basic idea correct. Why your index.html is not updated is a tough question to answer to since you're not providing any code – please include your Service Worker code. Keep in mind that depending on the logic implemented in the Service Worker, it doesn't necessarily honor the HTTP caching headers and will cache everything including the index.html file, as it seems now is happening.

In order to have the app work also in offline mode, you would probably want to use a *network-first* SW strategy. Using network-first the browser tries to load files from the web but if it doesn't succeed it falls back to the latest cached version of the particular file it tried to get. Another option would be to choose what is called a *stale-while-revalidate* strategy. That first gives the user the old file (which is super fast) and then updates the file in the background. There are other strategies as well, I suggest you read through the documentation of the most widely used SW library Workbox (https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-strategies).

One thing to keep in mind: 
In all other strategies except "skip SW and go to the network", you cannot really ensure the user gets the latest version of the index.html. It is not possible. If the SW gives something back from the cache, it could be an old version and that's that. In these situations what is usually done is a notification to the user that a new version of the app has been donwloaded in the background. Basically user would load the app, see the version that was available in the cache, and SW would then check for updates. If an update was found (there was a new index.html and, because of that, new service-worker.js), the user would see a notification telling that the page should be refreshed. You can also trigger the SW to check for an update from the server manually from your own JS code if you want. In that situation, too, you would show a notification to the user.

Does this help you?

Comment: I didn't provide service worker code because there is no caching logic in there. I decided to add those meta tags (as an attempt to prevent caching) also to the head of the html page, as below. I'll see if that works, but the link you provided may be useful and the explanation made the things clearer. Thanks a lot
`<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">`
`<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">`
`<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">`

Comment: So was it helpfull??